# What's wrong with my query? ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do a simple INSERT conditional query, but I keep getting this error **ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"**

Why?

```
INSERT INTO jobs (redflags) VALUES (11) WHERE id = 227;
```

Comment: WHERE id = 227; is for what purpose here? you are not selecting records from any table.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you want to update table:

```
UPDATE jobs  SET redflags = 11 WHERE id = 227;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to do.

**1. Copy values from one table into another (`INSERT / SELECT`):**

```sql
INSERT INTO jobs (redflags)
SELECT 11
FROM Source_Table
WHERE id = 227;
```

**2. Add a single row into a table:**

```
INSERT INTO jobs (redflags) 
VALUES (11);
```

Alternatively:

```
INSERT INTO jobs (id, redflags) 
VALUES (227, 11);
```

**3. Update values:**

```
UPDATE jobs 
SET redflags = 11
WHERE id = 227;
```